# New users cannot ask questions in a comment to help them make their answer

Tags: discussion

I was reviewing First Posts from users.  One user asked a question in his answer to a question, like `are you doing this?`.

Now maybe this is the answer and the poster just phrased it weirdly, but it got me thinking.  What if a new user needs to ask the OP for clarification on a question before answering?  Right now they can't.

I think it makes the site a bit uninviting to new users, they can't use tools that will help them start to become involved.

Is there a solution to this that I have over looked?

Comment: Then they shouldn't answer.  50 rep isn't hard to get, either by suggesting edits, or answering other things they *can* answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are... lots of questions. *Lots* of questions. Thousands more every day. On nearly any topic imaginable.

If a given question isn't answerable in its current state, then... **Find one whose author bothered to include sufficient information**. This is a much better use of everyone's time, and rewards the folks who put a bit more work into their questions.

Alternately... New users can just *guess*. If you *think* you know the unstated details of the problem that led to the question and can answer it, then put that in your answer along with your solution. Not a great idea if the question is unclear enough that you might easily be wrong, but if you have an answer to a problem that's *never* been asked about before this can be a reasonable bet.